# Mock association in view spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I'm writing a view spec for a form, with nested attributes. I **plan** this form to include fields for associated model. I mocked up a primary model with mock_model. And now, I need to stub an association to be able to build fields for it. How can I implement that? I imagine the following code:

```
describe 'hotels/new.html.erb' do

  before(:each) do
    assign(:hotel, mock_model('Hotel').as_new_record.as_null_object)
    # I feel something missing here
  end

  it 'has room price field'
    # Association - Room will belong to hotel
    render
    expect(rendered).to have_field 'hotel_room_attributes_0_price'
  end
end
```

In hotels/new.html.erb I have a form with field for block:

```
<%= form_for @hotel do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :room do |r| %>
    <%= r.text_field :price %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

How can I stub this association to be able to render its fields?

Answer (score 0):

A stub is created like this:

```
hotel.stub(:rooms).and_return(whatever_you_want_returned)
```

You could either return a fake, or an actual model, but the and_return part is optional. If you want to stv this method for all instances of hotel, do this:

```
Hotel.any_instance.stub(:rooms)
```